# Laravel - How to retrieve the last saved data from the database and display it

Tags: laravel, api

I am developing a client portal application using Angular-7 as frontend and Laravel-5.8 as the backend. From the Laravel Query (API) below, anyone that gets to the site can send quote (Registered or not):

```
    public function createClientQuote(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'phone' => 'required|max:14',
                    'commodity' => 'required'
        ]);

        $clientquote = new ClientQuote;
        $clientquote->first_name=$request->get('first_name');
        $clientquote->last_name=$request->get('last_name');
        $clientquote->email=$request->get('email');
        $clientquote->phone=$request->get('phone');
        $clientquote->commodity=$request->get('commodity');
        $clientquote->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!'
        ], 201);
    }
```

I want to write another Laravel query (API) that as soon as the one above is saved into the database, the information will be immediately retrieved and displayed to the screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should get the list of quotes from the database right after creating the new quote on DB. Then, send the array of quotes as the API response. The endpoint you share is for creating a quote but does your API have an endpoint to retrieve a list of quotes? If so, that endpoint should return the new quote after it's added to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with :

```
return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!',
'Data'=> $clientquote
        ], 201);
```

Or :

```
return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!',
    'Data'=> ClientQuote::latest()->first()
            ], 201);
```